# Do any cities besides Chicago and Detroit have team names that are related?

Tags: history

One of Chicago's baseball teams - the Cubs - grows up to become their football team - the Bears.  In Detroit, they have Lions and Tigers (but sadly, no Bears - oh my!).

Are the names of the professional sports teams in any other American cities related in a similar way?

Comment: Related is not a meaningful term in the way you are using it here.  Any two team names could be defined as related as far as I can tell; so this is an opinion based question.  Appropriate for the chat room, but not here.

Comment: what about the Nets/Mets/Jets? there are so many ways you can claim "related" that it loses meaning

Comment: @joe - How are Bears and Cubs, or Lions and Tigers, not meaningfully related?

Comment: Each pair has a different relationship.  Related is not defined in a single consistent way that doesn't have a vague meaning.  The answers it's already drawn exemplify this problem.

Comment: Also - none of those tags are appropriate (there isn't really one, in part because this question doesn't belong here.)  I'll leave history on as it's the least inappropriate one.

Comment: @Joe - No, the answers prove that the question is clear.  Both are correct.

Comment: I don't know if questions like this would normally be considered okay on [scifi.se] - even there I'd be surprised - but for a normal SE-type site, questions that don't have a clear answer are clearly off-topic.  The point is, the definition of "related" is unclear: Lions and Tigers are related because of a movie quote?  You could define almost any two teams to be related ("mets" and "cubs" both have four letters, "dolphins" and "marlins" are both aquatic, "dodgers" and "raiders" are both lawbreakers...)  so the question has no useful meaning.

Comment: It's a discussion question, and would be perhaps interesting for a discussion forum: but that's not the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: @Joe - No, ffs, lions and tigers are genetically related.  They are both felines of the genus panthera.  Literally related.  The same way apes are related.

Comment: @Joe - your other examples are ridiculous.  No, "Dodgers" aren't lawbreakers.  The Brooklyn Dodgers got their name from an epithet used by people from Manhattan in regards to people from Brooklyn.  There were trolleys in Brooklyn, but not Manhattan, so people from Brooklyn were called "trolley Dodgers".  Buccaneers and Pirates might be related, but no, not Raiders and Dodgers, and certainly not Mets and Cubs, since the former means "metropolitans" and the latter means "baby bear".

Comment: Cubs, Bears, Bruins - related.  Lions, Tigers, Panthers - related.  Braves, Indians, Redskins - related.  Pirates, Buccaneers, Raiders - related.  Angels, Devils (arguably Saints) - related.  White Sox, Red Sox - related.  Jets, Rockets - related.

Comment: Why? Because they're all objectively the same (names for bears;  members of the genus Panthera;  names for Native Americans; names for pirates), or extremely similar in purpose and function (rockets and jets - things you fly in), or categorical opposites (devils and angels).

Comment: Given Chicago's stock trading history, Bulls and Bears are related:  just stock brokers with different attitudes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same cities:
 - Colorado Rockies and Colorado Avalanche. 
 - Dallas Cowboys(Team Logo Star) and Dallas Stars.
 - Houston Astros and Houston Rockets.

There might be more but I lived in those cities.

Answer (score 2):

The New England Patriots (NFL) and the New England Revolution (MLS) both play in Foxborough in the Greater Boston area.

I would argue that similar to Cubs turning into Bears, the **Patriots** (Adams/Revere et al, not Bellichek and Brady) started with protests in Boston, including a well known incident with a tea shipment, before taking up armed hostilities in Massachusetts. This later turned into a **Revolution** with the support of the other 12 colonies.

Comment: Are we now counting soccer as a professional sport in the US?

Comment: @Coach-D, I would say it is a professional league. The base Salary appears to be 50K USD, but with some players earning millions. https://www.mlsplayers.org/images/September%2015%202015%20Salary%20Information%20-%20By%20Club.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In honor of back to the future day being yesterday:

The Atlanta Braves and the Washington Redskins were both originally the Boston Braves (and then the football team switched from playing at the baseball teams stadium to the Boston Red Sox's stadium and switched their name to Redskins).  Both of these teams eventually moved out, such that now Atlanta and DC have team names that are related.

Answer (score 0):

St. Louis used to have both the football and baseball Cardinals.  Can't get more related than that.